# Install extension in PostgreSQL database via migration without superuser role?

Tags: postgresql, security, sequelize.js

We are using migrations (via Sequelize, in JavaScript) to maintain changes to our database. I have a need to add a `CREATE EXTENSION` call but since I am running as the database creator, and not superuser, I get a `permission denied to create extension`.

Is there a way to modify security on a single database to allow a user to install an extension via a migration file? IOW, when I create the "naked" database and apply my permissions, can I set security up to allow `CREATE EXTENSION` and `DROP EXTENSION` for a specific user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find a way to do this inside a migration file.

The technique we ended up using was to have a subfolder in the migration folder, called `postgres` to hold anything that must be run as superuser. The subfolder contained the migrations and a config file for running things as a superuser. So, the command-line becomes:

```
$ sequelize db:migrate --migrations-path "migrations/postgres" --config "migrations/postgres"
$ sequelize db:migrate
```

The inconvenience of a more complex command-line was mitigated by the fact that the "special" migrations that required this isolation also made them more evident.

Comment: Please note that if you have a `.sequelizerc` file, any config setting in there will cause a bug to surface when using the `--config` switch in the CLI. This has been reported by others in the [project](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/42)

Comment: Note that the command line two-step becomes `sequelize db:migrate --migrations-path "migrations/postgres" --config "migrations/postgres/config.json`, then `sequelize db:migrate --migrations-path "migrations" --config "migrations/config.json"`. And, you must remove any `.sequelizerc` file.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no setting for [CREATE ROLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createrole.html) for granular `CREATE/DROP EXTENSION` control. I assume, it depends on the extension you use, but you based on the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createextension.html):

> Loading an extension requires the same privileges that would be
>   required to create its component objects. For most extensions this
>   means superuser or database owner privileges are needed. The user who
>   runs CREATE EXTENSION becomes the owner of the extension for purposes
>   of later privilege checks, as well as the owner of any objects created
>   by the extension's script.

I was running into the same issue with `pg_trgm` extension, but even setting role to database owner did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking, here is how to create an extension via a sequelize migration. It doesn't address the secondary question of user roles however. But this works for me.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query('CREATE EXTENSION extensionName;');
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query('DROP EXTENSION extensionName;');
  }
};
```